# sagemath returns 0 for indefinite integral

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, integral

Trying the following:

```
t = var('t')
f = t * cos(pi / t)
g = sqrt(1 + f.diff())
    
show(g.integral(t))
```

returns 0. This seems unexpected -- I am not expecting a closed-form result for this, but it seems like it is definitely not 0.

Is this a sagemath bug, or is my question incorrect?

Comment: What version of Sage are you using? What OS? (I don't see the problem with OS X and version 9.1 of SageMath.)

Comment: Note: many more Sage experts visit
[Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org)
so questions asked there typically
get more and faster answers.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: I am on version 8.6, ubuntu 19.04 (I think it's whatever I got from `apt-get install ...`).

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre I tried to post this question (verbatim) and hit an error message that said something like "we think your post is spam and won't allow it," and so came here.

Comment: @PatrickCollins - Sorry about that! Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I indeed get 0 with Sage 8.6 and 8.7, but I get `integrate(sqrt(pi*sin(pi/t)/t + cos(pi/t) + 1), t)` with Sage 8.8. So I guess it was a bug which has now been fixed, although I haven't tried finding the ticket dealing with it.

Comment: @PatrickCollins -- you can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 to get a more recent Sage via `apt install` or `apt-get install`. Otherwise you could get Sage 9.1 from Conda or from the download page on the Sage website; or you can build Sage 9.2.beta5 from source!